# the else inside if nest doesn't work in php

Tags: php

i dont know what's wrong with this code, the statement in else doesn't echo out. i've read it numerous time and still cannot figure it out.. :(

```
    if(isset($_POST['ad_lg'])){
        $lg= $_POST['ad_lg'];

        if(!empty($lg)){
            $insert_lg = "INSERT INTO 'urlg' VALUE('$lg')";
            $insert_lg_run= mysql_query($insert_lg);
            header("location: index.php");                  
        }else{
            echo 'sth';
        }
    }
```

help me please. thanks in advance^^

Comment: else will print when there is no value posted in `ad_lg`

Comment: yes. i left the  ad_lg empty but the else didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Move your second `if`statement from the first `if`:

```
$lg = '';
if(isset($_POST['ad_lg'])){
    $lg= $_POST['ad_lg'];
}

if(!empty($lg)){
        $insert_lg = "INSERT INTO 'urlg' VALUE('$lg')";
        $insert_lg_run= mysql_query($insert_lg);
        header("location: index.php");                  
    }else{
        echo 'sth';
}
```

Comment: Yes of course `$lg` come from a form. To test either `sth` value appear or not --> Try submit with `empty` value. I meant you submit the form without any value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an else on the `isset(...)` aswell

```
if(isset($_POST['ad_lg'])){
    $lg= $_POST['ad_lg'];

    if(!empty($lg)){
        $insert_lg = "INSERT INTO 'urlg' VALUE('$lg')";
        $insert_lg_run= mysql_query($insert_lg);
        header("location: index.php");                  
    }else{
        echo 'sth';
    }
}else{
    echo 'sth';
}
```

otherwise you will echo nothing if `$_POST['ad_lg']` is not set.

Comment: That sounds as if there is something else completly wrong, that can't be seen in the code-snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For this code to reach `echo 'sth'`, you would need your `ad_lg` POST variable to be both set *and* empty.

I believe `ad_lg=""` would work.

Comment: errr.. i left the form empty so it was set and empty. right? stil the else didn't echo out..

Comment: depending on the type of input in your form, `ad_lg` may not be set.
for instance, an unchecked checkbox will not send an empty value, it will just not send that field, which thus will be unset.
so you should double-check what your client app is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
if(!empty($_POST['ad_lg'])){ 
  $lg= $_POST['ad_lg']; 
  $insert_lg = "INSERT INTO 'urlg' VALUE('$lg')"; 
  $insert_lg_run= mysql_query($insert_lg); 
  header("location: index.php"); 
} else{ 
  echo 'sth'; 
}
```

> Empty checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for
>   null, "", 0, etc

With `empty`, the following things are considered empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE

Comment: i echo out the $lg= $_POST['ad_lg'];
i left the form empty and it didn't give any value. why the else didn't work? :'(

Comment: both are same friend @ゆにたどうえ

Comment: i left the form empty and it didn't give any value. why the else didn't work? :'(

Comment: if(!empty($_POST['ad_lg'])){
    $lg= $_POST['ad_lg'];
    $insert_lg = "INSERT INTO 'urlg' VALUE('$lg')";
    $insert_lg_run= mysql_query($insert_lg);
    header("location: index.php");
}
else{
    echo 'sth';
}

Answer (score 0):

isset actually checks whether the variable exist and has a value.
so your $lg has a value inside if(isset), so else won't print.